# Editor javascript dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i want to use kendo ui editor but i have a problem,
i added these script to view:

1. jquery.js
2. kendo.core.js
3. kendo.data.js
4. kendo.popup.js
5. kendo.list.js
6. kendo.combobox.js
7. kendo.dropdownlist.js
8. kendo.userevents.js
9. kendo.draganddrop.js
10. kendo.window.js
11. kendo.slider.js
12. kendo.colorpicker.js
13. kendo.listview.js (Image Browser feature)
14. kendo.upload.js (Image Browser feature)
15. kendo.imagebrowser.js (Image Browser feature)
16. kendo.editor.js

everything work great else Imagebrowser , when i click on [InsertImage] ,i get following message :**undefined is not a function**

but when i add Kendo.all.min.js instead of above scripts then Imagebrowser work fine.

Can you tell me that how can i sovle it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are including all of that you have in your list? Did you check in your browser inspector that all are being found? I've just tried this and works fine on my system with latest KendoUI official release.

Comment: Yes , i check it again, all script load successfully,
Can you upload your sample?

Comment: you didn't add any script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must added these references:

kendo.selectable.js
kendo.editable.js

Comment: also for create folder we need add these references
kendo.calendar.min.js
kendo.datepicker.min.js
kendo.numerictextbox.min.js
kendo.binder.min.js
I think kendo ui is not optimize yet (for dependency scripts)